# Merge several Dataframes with outside temperature and power generation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, iot

I have several dataframes of heating devices which are containing data over 1 year. One time step is 15 min, each df have two columns: outside_temp and heat_generation. Each df looks like this:

```
        outside_temp     heat_production
    0       11.1              200
    1       11.1              150
    2       11.0              245
    3       11.0               0
    4       11.0              300
    5       10.9              49
    6
    .
    .
    .
  35037    -5.1               450
  35038    -5.1               450
  35039    -5.1               450
  35040    -5.2               600
```

I now want to know at which outside_temp I need how much heat_production for all heat devices(and therefore for all dataframes) -> I was thinking about groupby oder somthing else. But I dont know how to handel this amount of data the best way. When directly merging the dfs there is the problem that the outside temperature is there several times and the heat production of course differs. To solve this, I could imagine to take the average heat_production for each device at a given outside_temperature. Of course it can also be the case that a device was not measuring a specific temperature (e.g. the device is located in warmer or colder area -> Therefore NaN Values are possbile)
At the end I want to get kind of Polynomial/Sigmoid function to see how much heat_production is necessary at a given outside temperature

At the end I want to have a dataframe like this:

```
    outside_temp     heat_production_average_device_1  heat_production_average_device_2 ...etc
    -20.0                         790                            NaN                                  
    -19.9                         789                            NaN
    -19.8                         788                            790
    -19.7                         NaN                            780
    -19.6                         770                            NaN
     .
     .
     .
    19.6                          34                              0
    19.7                          32                              0
    19.8                          30                              0
    19.9                          32                              0
    20.0                           0                              0
```

Any idea whats the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> df1
   outside_temp  heat_production
0          11.1              200
1          11.1              150
2          11.0              245

>>> df2
   outside_temp  heat_production
3          11.0                0
4          11.0              300
5          10.9               49
```

Doing:

```
def my_func(i, df):
   renamer = {'heat_production': f'heat_production_average_device_{i}'}
   return (df.groupby('outside_temp')
             .mean()
             .rename(columns=renamer))
   

dfs = [df1, df2]
dfs = [my_func(i+1, df) for i, df in enumerate(dfs)]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              heat_production_average_device_1  heat_production_average_device_2
outside_temp
11.0                                     245.0                             150.0
11.1                                     175.0                               NaN
10.9                                       NaN                              49.0
```